# Did Google stop supporting Android Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, eclipse-plugin

If the question is not for here, I will remove it.

Does someone knows if Android has stopped supporting the Eclipse Plugin?
Now when you enter their site from googling "Android SDK" you get to download Android Studio, and I can't find where is the Eclipse plugin...
I remember they said they won't stop supporting it, but well, its Google after all...
So someone knows?

Comment: Things are definitely in favor of Android Studio these days.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse with ADT is no loger in active development. It's possible there may be occasional bug fixes to resolve critical issues and keep it operational, but there will probably never be any new features added, and the ADT plugin may be completely abandoned in the future.

Comment: http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/12/08/android-studio-1-0-officially-released-eclipse-adt-longer-active-development/

Comment: There is also the [Eclipse Andmore Project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore). From their homepage: _The purpose of Andmore is to provide Android Eclipse tooling without having to go through multiple steps_: It seems the project re-uses the Google ADT plug-ins

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann what does that mean, I want to use Eclipse in the future with everything up-to-date from Android, I really don't want to switch to studio...

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer I don't know what the implications are, you could ask this question on the [projects mailing list](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore/contact).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Android Development Tools page](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html):

> **Note:** If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving projects, see [Migrating to Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

Answer (score 2):

New development for an eclipse specific Android set of tools is happening with the new Eclipse Andmore Project. https://github.com/eclipse/andmore  It is picking up with ADT left off and working to add the missing functionality and integration with Gradle.

Comment: what does that mean, explain please. Will this allow us to work with Eclipse only in the future, with everything working and up-to-date?

Comment: Andmore is a fork of the ADT tooling, and a new project at eclipse.  It isn't released yet, but the goal is to allow you to continue to develop Android applications with eclipse, and also to support new features that are currently only available in Android Studio (i.e AARs).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google stopped supporting Eclipse.  Android Studio is much more robust anyways and switching over is not too hard.  If you have any questions, feel free to post and I'll help out.

Comment: Please provide some arguments, when you're saying that something is "much more robust", because my personal experience is quite the opposite.