# Android created app does not play sound

Tags: java, android, wav, smartphone

1st of all sorry for this, possible, stupid question...

I'm new in this android studio world and i'm struggling a lot...
I've created an app that just show some pictures and an image button that play some sounds. In the emulator everything works fine, I click in the image button and the sounds are reproduced.
But when I run the app in the smartphone the sounds do not play...

I guess that the problem is the lack of the WAV files in the smartphone?
but i've no idea how to do that... i've created a raw directory in the project that is in my laptop, copied the mp3 files there, as I did with the pictures.
The pictures are showing properly in the smartphone, but not the sound.

The app is currently in my smartphone, i can run it, but can't find it in the smartphone files...

What am i missing?

thank you

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse for Android in 2017? Should be using Android Studio.  On your question, are you saving the MP3s in the project or on your laptop? If the MP3s are on your laptop make sure you place those MP3s into the Android project that way when the application is downloaded to any device, the MP3s are going to the device also. You can place those MP3 files into the raw folder under res.

Comment: @Adam Gardner What's wrong with Eclipse for Android?

Comment: @Michel_T. Eclipse has been let go by Google, they are not developing nor supporting Eclipse any longer for Android as of 2015. Android Studio is the official IDE for Android and is a lot more robust. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28531957/4219444

Comment: @AdamGardner, sorry, my bad, i'm using Android Studio. Regarding your question, i've created the raw folder under res and added the files there. But i don't think that they are being downloaded into the smartphone.

Comment: @Michel_T., thank you for the reply. I can post the code, but i don't think that the problem is in the code since the app it's working properly in the emulator

Comment: Make sure you have the right audio channel unmuted on your phone ;)

Comment: Sorry, the files are WAV files, not MP3, not sure if that's the problem

Comment: @TobiasG, I feel so stupid now... the multimédia volume was in fact muted for some reason... sorry and thank you